# lightningQuickAction and transparent background color in Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, css, lightning-design-system

I added `force:lightningQuickAction` interface to my lightning component in order to access the component from Salesforce1.

Everything works correctly but I am unable to understand how to apply the same white background color that is applied when using the component in any other context.

This is how the component appears in Salesforce1:

[image]

Salesforce official components don't have this problem:

[image]

How do I apply the white background all around to be white like it is for any other Salesforce standard component?